# React - how to wrap a table row with Link

Tags: reactjs, html-table, react-router

I have a table that I built using [react mui](https://v3.material-ui.com/demos/tables/#tables). In that table I have a row, that looks like this:

```
<TableRow
    hover
    onClick={() => onRowClicked(item)}
    role="checkbox"
    aria-checked={isSelected}
    tabIndex={-1}
    key={item.id}
    data-testid={item.id}
    selected={isSelected}
    className={classes.tr}
  >
    <TableCell padding="checkbox" classes={{body: classes.smWidth}} onClick={(event) => onCheckboxClick(event, item.id)}>
      <Checkbox checked={isSelected}/>
    </TableCell>
    <TableCell component="th" scope="row" classes={{body: classes.id}}>{item.id}</TableCell>
    <TableCell align="left">{item.text}</TableCell>
    <TableCell align="left">{item.code}</TableCell>
    <TableCell align="left">{item.type}</TableCell>
    <TableCell align="left"><StatusLabel status={item.substatus || item.status} size="large"/></TableCell>
    <TableCell align="left">{getElapsedTime(new Date(item.updated), now)}</TableCell>
  </TableRow>
```

And this works fine, but instead of using onClick function to navigate to each item, I would like to use link, so that I also get on control/cmd click possibility to open link in a new tab. I have tried just by wrapping the whole `TableRow` with `Link` component:

```
<Link to={`/${item.id}`}>
 <TableRow
    hover
    role="checkbox"
    aria-checked={isSelected}
    tabIndex={-1}
    key={item.id}
    data-testid={item.id}
    selected={isSelected}
    className={classes.tr}
  >
    <TableCell padding="checkbox" classes={{body: classes.smWidth}} onClick={(event) => onCheckboxClick(event, item.id)}>
      <Checkbox checked={isSelected}/>
    </TableCell>
    <TableCell component="th" scope="row" classes={{body: classes.id}}>{item.id}</TableCell>
    <TableCell align="left">{item.text}</TableCell>
    <TableCell align="left">{item.code}</TableCell>
    <TableCell align="left">{item.type}</TableCell>
    <TableCell align="left"><StatusLabel status={item.substatus || item.status} size="large"/></TableCell>
    <TableCell align="left">{getElapsedTime(new Date(item.updated), now)}</TableCell>
  </TableRow>
 </link>
```

But, then the whole table styling is out of place. What is the right way to do this then?

Comment: Just to confirm, have you intentionally linked to v3 of the MUI documentation?

Comment: FYI doing that would generate an invalid html. I would suggest either adding onClick with history.push or adding Link inside td, which is not optimal i assume.

Comment: @lek yes, I am using v3, so that link was intentional

Comment: @GiedriusVičkus I am currently using history.push with onClick, but that way I can't get open link in a new tab with control/cmd click

Comment: @Leff I don't think a nice way to handle this exists. You could have <a> as a sibling to <tr>, and add some css (container {position:relative}, a {position:absolute, top/left/right/bottom: 0}) to position it in a way, that it would be on top of <tr>. But then again, you would have to handle checkbox somehow.